# JS: Unexpected error message appear when private method is not accessible after "this unbinding"

Tags: javascript, class, this, private-methods

When I intentionally make "this" of a method as undefined using a high order function and try to access the private method in the function(presented below as 'deprivedMethod2'), **the error message is quite weird.**

```
expected message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#privateMethod')
actual message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TestClass')
```

Below is how to reproduce the situation.

```js
class TestClass {
    publicWithPublic() {
        this.publicMethod();
    }

    publicWithPrivate() {
        this.#privateMethod();
    }
    
    publicMethod() {
        console.log('public');
    }
    
    #privateMethod() {
        console.log('private');
    }

}

// function to unbind this
const depriveThis = (func) => () => func();

const obj = new TestClass();

const deprivedMethod1 = depriveThis(obj.publicWithPublic)
const deprivedMethod2 = depriveThis(obj.publicWithPrivate);

deprivedMethod1();
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicMethod')
deprivedMethod2();
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TestClass')  => why???
```

```
expected message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#privateMethod')
actual message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TestClass')
```

Here I understood that error occurs because "this" is unbound going through depriveThis function.
However, I could not understand why "reading 'TestClass'" occurs when trying to access privateMethod.
I expected "Reading #privateMethod"!

**I wonder how JS knew the function was bound to "TestClass" even after it lost "this" binding.**

If you are aware of the slightest hint, please let me know and it will be a big help :)

Comment: FWIW, you can remove `depriveThis` for the same outcome…